# iPhone hotspot prioritized over ethernet

Tags: iphone, macos, tethering

In Yosemite, when I connect my iPhone to my Macbook Air through USB the iPhone becomes a internet hotspot for my Mac, even though I've connected the MBA via ethernet. If I enable Wifi, then Wifi is prioritized.

Can I change so that ethernet is prioritized over the iPhone?

Answer (score 9, accepted):

1. Open System Preferences
2. Select Network preferences pane
3. Click gear menu in lower-left corner of Network pane and choose "Select Service Order..."
4. Drag the services into whichever order you want
5. Click OK

[image: Screenshot of Network pane with Service Order panel open]